# How to print only certain characters?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, ls

I have to translate the permissions of a file this way:

```
r ► c 
w ► s 
x ► e
```

Then, I must extract the group of characters which are related to owner group. Last step is to print that group of characters without "-" (only letters).

I managed to write a command till now:

```
student@vm-uso ~team2 $ ls -l partition
-rw-r--r-- 1 student student 10485760 nov 24 21:04 partition
student@vm-uso ~team2 $ ls -l partition | cut -d ' ' -f 1| tr rwx cse | cut -c5-7
c--
student@vm-uso ~team2 $
```

Forwards, I have to add another '|' in order to print only the letter (without the characters '-').

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots of text; post the actual text...

Comment: If you want to filter out the `-`s, then append to the end of your command ...`| sed 's/-//g'`.  `sed` is a tool used to edit inline a stream of text, `s/foo/bar/g` means to replace all instances of `foo` with `bar` (in this case, nothing), and the final `g` means to do so *g*lobally.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please [edit] your question and 1) replace the screenshot with a copy/paste of the actual text (see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help on formatting your post) 2) Show us the output you want. Don't describe it, give us an actual example that we can produce for you.

Comment: Another way to filter out the dashes is `| tr -d -`, which is a little bit like `tr - "\0"` except it doesn't insert nul bytes, it just deletes the dashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this command:

```
ls -l partition | cut -c5-7 | tr rwx cse |sed 's/-//'
```

You can remove the one extra command(`cut -d ' ' -f 1`) and replace it with your last cut command(`cut -c5-7`)  and also add `sed 's/-//'` at the end to remove all `-`s. Now you are done. you didn't need to adding extra `|`.

And even better: you can also change the dash(`-` character with Null character(`\0`) as following):

```
ls -l partition | cut -c5-7 | tr 'rwx-' 'cse\0'
```

Replaced `-` char with null character(`\0`).

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way without `ls`:

```
getfacl -c partition | sed -n '/group::/{s/.*:://;y/rwx/cse/;s/-//g;p;}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative (piping two `tr` commands):

`ls -l partition | cut -c5-7 | tr -dc rwx | tr rwx cse`